# Explanation of SVG path?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG path that I'm trying to dynamically create, but the resources I've found on SVG paths don't describe that path I have.

This is the path:
`m41.5 1.5v15l-40 10v100h60v-100l-10-10v-15z`

I don't even understand the start of it - the `m41.6`; `m` moves the pen to a coordinate relative to the last known position. I assume this is the origin? but everywhere I've found says that the syntax is `m x,y`. If I supply `m41.6,0` instead, the svg just disappears - opening in Inkscape doesn't show it either.

I need a step-by-step explanation please of each term.

The full SVG is:

```
<svg id="svg11" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 63 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="m41.5 1.5v15l-40 10v100h60v-100l-10-10v-15z" fill="#ffd42a"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: "If I supply m41.6,0 instead, the svg just disappears" can you show the full `d` value that produces this? `m41.6,0v15l-40 10v100h60v-100l-10-10v-15z` should just work: https://jsfiddle.net/2qpy09a7/.  As for the rest of the path declaration it's hard to know how we should explain it to you. Each commands do map to a well defined and documented action: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths Your declaration doesn't use anything that seems surprising.

Comment: oh hang on, so `m41.6 1.5` can also be written as `m41.6,1.5`?

Comment: so the steps are: 1. m41.5 1.5 2. v15 3. l-40 10 4. v100 5. h60 6. v-100 7. l-10-10 8. v-15 9.z?

Comment: I understand now... the spaces and lack of spaces were confusing me (first time actually trying to understand the SVG language). The path can be rewritten as: `m41.5,1.5 v15 l-40,10 v100 h60 v-100 l-10,-10 v-15 z` which makes it far more clear the distinctions in pen steps. You led me to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Yes you have many ways to rewrite these same commands: https://jsfiddle.net/sg41t65e/

Comment: Paste your d-path in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor and play with it

Comment: Very cool little app @Danny'365CSI'Engelman , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> the resources I've found on SVG paths don't describe that path I have.

Then I guess you didn't consider reading the SVG specification? :)

Try reading the [Paths section of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-paths) . It's all explained quite clearly there.

**Explanation**

```
m41.5 1.5
```

Move to (41.5, 1.5).  `m` is a relative move normally, but the spec says:

> If a relative moveto (m) appears as the first element of the path, then it is treated as a pair of absolute coordinates.

Coordinates can be separated by a comma, whitespace, both, or even neither. For example, `M1.5.5` is a valid path command, since a coord can't have more than one decimal point, and leading zeros are optional.
`M 1.5,0.5`, `M1.5 0.5`, `M1.5, 0.5`, `M 1.5 .5`, and `M1.5.5` are all equivalent.

```
v15
```

Draw a line vertically (downward) by 15 units

```
l-40 10
```

Draw a line left by 40 and down by 10 units.

```
v100
```

Draw a line down by 100 units

```
h60
```

Draw a line right by 60 units

```
v-100
```

Draw a line upwards by 100 units

```
l-10-10
```

Draw a line diagonally up and left by (10,10)

```
v-15
```

Draw a line vertically upwards by 15 units

```
z
```

Close the path (ie back to 41.5,1.5)

Answer (score 0):

The path can be rewritten as:

```
m41.5,1.5 v15 l-40,10 v100 h60 v-100 l-10,-10 v-15 z
```

or

```
m41.5 1.5 v15 l-40 10 v100 h60 v-100 l-10 -10 v-15 z
```

This better separates the individual pen movements which I was confused by when they were all merged together in the original version.